# Error loading an H2O model and then predict

Tags: h2o

I am able to save an H2O model, load it again and then show it...

```
# save the model
model_path_2 = h2o.save_model(model=my_xgboost_2, path="tmp/mymodel", force=True)
print (model_path_2)

>>>/home/dell/Documents/Enigma/tmp/mymodel/XGBoost_model_python_1503367354328_27

# load the model
saved_model_2 = h2o.load_model(model_path_2)
```

but I cannot use it to predict.

```
saved_model_2.predict(test)

    >>>xgboost prediction progress: | (failed)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-fa76fd498ee6> in <module>()
----> 1 saved_model_2.predict(test)

/home/dell/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/model/model_base.py in predict(self, test_data)
    130         j = H2OJob(h2o.api("POST /4/Predictions/models/%s/frames/%s" % (self.model_id, test_data.frame_id)),
    131                    self._model_json["algo"] + " prediction")
--> 132         j.poll()
    133         return h2o.get_frame(j.dest_key)
    134 

/home/dell/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in poll(self, verbose_model_scoring_history)
     75             if (isinstance(self.job, dict)) and ("stacktrace" in list(self.job)):
     76                 raise EnvironmentError("Job with key {} failed with an exception: {}\nstacktrace: "
---> 77                                        "\n{}".format(self.job_key, self.exception, self.job["stacktrace"]))
     78             else:
     79                 raise EnvironmentError("Job with key %s failed with an exception: %s" % (self.job_key, self.exception))

OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_927b7278904ecf169173d48a23de4c10 failed with an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
stacktrace: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I can, however, predict on the model without saving it. I am using Python 3.6.1, and H2O 3.14.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4585?filter=21100) with H2O's XGBoost implementation and should be fixed soon.  It does not affect other H2O models.

Comment: I have also observed that nfolds with xgboost fails and when I train multiple models in a row (with different validation set seeds in lieu of cross-validation), the models gives weird results (all metrics will be equal to 0.5). Is this also a known XGBoost issue?

Comment: Is the above issue with saving and loading models fixed in the nightly bleeding edge?

Comment: For the first issue, can you provide a reproducible example and file a JIRA ticket?  That sounds like a bug.  The save/load issue has been worked on yet, but it's a high priority item, so it should be fixed soon.